# while exporting the data from database using spool,large set of data column is dividing into two rows.how to avoid it?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, spool

I have used these commands to align the output properly.But the problem still exists. Can someone please help me? I have done a lot of research but couldn't find a proper answer.

```
spool on
set verify off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 3000;
set pagesize 50000;
set wrap on;
set long 100000;
set longchunksize 1000000;
set colsep '|';
spool F:\data\tabledata\products.txt;
set trimspool on;
select * from products;
spool off;
```

[in my image one data column which is CLOB data type is dividing into two rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWq2W.png)

Comment: Mysql is a different product with different syntax

Comment: I have attached the image also. please check it once.

Comment: It is SQL plus.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line

Comment: i have gone through that before.It couldn't solve my problem.Any other suggestions?please.

Comment: That's suprising because it did work for me. But have it your way :)

Comment: can you please check the screenshot once? because it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in column datatype length, if there you have, for example, `Varchar2 (100)` and is in that column you have data with length `less than 100` so the `Trimspool ON` will not trim datatype length - that's the problem you reached (I don't know whether it's logically like this, but really it's happening). 
The easy way to do your query output by concatenation, try like this:

```
spool F:\data\tabledata\products.txt;

SELECT col1 || '|' || col2 || '|' || col3 
FROM Products;

spool off;
```

Comment: it is not showing output for all columns.the row is terminating on printing after 5 columns

Comment: even if I use this I don't get the column names which are necessary

Comment: Can you share your Product tables definition?

Answer (score 0):

The settings for large object types BLOB and CLOB are different from ordinary text fields. Please include the following settings before the query and see if it resolves the problem:

```
set long 500
set longchunksize 500
```

[This blog post](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2008/07/set-longchunksize.html) discusses effects of `long` and `longchunksize`.